# basereducer is not a function - Redux Toolkit with createasyncthunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using `redux-toolkit` to acquire accessToken from MSAL and `redux-persist` to persist the store in localStorage. I'm getting search results in clientlisting page. When I refresh the page it was working fine. But few minutes ago it throws me an error "Error in function eval in ./node_modules/redux-persist/es/persistReducer.js:144 baseReducer is not a function" I couldn't figure where am I doing wrong

store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import usersReducer from "./userSlice";
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
const persistConfig = { key: 'root', storage, }
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, usersReducer)
export const store = configureStore(
  { 
    reducer: { 
      users: persistedReducer,
    }
  })
export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

userSlice.js

```js
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { loginRequest } from "./authConfig";
import { msalInstance } from "./pages/index";

export const fetchUsersToken = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/fetchUsersToken",
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      const token = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(dispatch)
        .then((data) => data.accessToken)
      return token
    } catch (error) {
      return error.response.data
    }
  }
);

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    users: null,
    loading: true
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchUsersToken.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true
      })
      .addCase(fetchUsersToken.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false,
        state.users = action.payload
      })
      .addCase(fetchUsersToken.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false

      });
  }
})

export default usersSlice.reducer;
```

index.js

```js
import React from "react"
import { Provider, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {persistor, store} from "../../store";
import Footer from "../Footer"
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles"
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
// Global styles and component-specific styles.

//For changing default blue color for mui text-fields
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: "#000000" },
  },
})

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          {children}
          <Footer/>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
)

export default Layout
```

LandingPage.js ( where I'm dispatching the action.)

```js
const request = {
  ...loginRequest,
  account: accounts[0]
}
store.dispatch(fetchUsersToken(request))
```

Here is my index.js ( where msalInstance initiated )

```
import React from "react"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser"
import { MsalProvider, useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react"
import { loginRequest, msalConfig } from "../authConfig"
import PageLayout from "../components/PageLayout"
import App from "./app"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"

//Redux
import { Provider, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {store} from "../store";

//Redux Ends here
export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig)

export default function Home() {

return (
<>
  <Helmet>
    <title>Client Engagement Lookup</title>
  </Helmet>
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
   
    {/* <Provider store={store}> */}
       <Layout>
      <PageLayout />
      </Layout>
      {/* </Provider> */}

  </MsalProvider>
 </>
 )
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copy/pasting the code you shared into a running codesandbox I wasn't able to reproduce the error you describe, but I do see some discrepancies in the code, specifically in the `userSlice.js` file.

The main discrepancy I see is that the thunk is incorrectly accessing the `thunkAPI`. `createAsyncThunk` [payload creators](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) *do* take two arguments, the first is the `arg` (*e.g. the  `request` object*) that is passed to the function and the second is the `thunkAPI` object. Update the thunk to correctly destructure `dispatch` and `getState` from the `thunkAPI` object.

```js
export const fetchUsersToken = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/fetchUsersToken",
  async (request, { dispatch, getState }) => { // <-- destructure thunkAPI
    try {
      const { accessToken } = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request);
      return accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      return error.response.data;
    }
  }
);
```

A second discrepancy I noticed was in the `fetchUsersToken.fulfilled` reducer case where a [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) was used between the lines to set the `loading` and `users` states. This doesn't really effect much though since each operand mutates the `state` independently, but should still be fixed for readability's and maintenance's sake.

```js
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    users: null,
    loading: true
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchUsersToken.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(fetchUsersToken.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;        // <-- own line, expression
        state.users = action.payload; // <-- own line, expression
      })
      .addCase(fetchUsersToken.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
      });
  }
});

export default usersSlice.reducer;
```

[image: Edit basereducer-is-not-a-function-redux-toolkit-with-createasyncthunk]

Comment: Hi Drew. Thanks for the response. After tweaking userSlice.js based on your suggestion, the fetchUsersToken is getting rejected always. Previously it was working. Only thing is this basereducer error pops up whenever I refresh the page

Comment: @Lakshmi Ah, I think I see what was going on now. The `request` object that was passed to the `fetchUsersToken` was named `dispatch` in the action and passed along to the `acquireTokenSilent` function. I've revised my answer a bit, please do check it out to see if that at least resolves the "rejected always" issue you just described.

Comment: Again,its getting rejected :(

Comment: @Lakshmi Can you edit your post to include this msalInstance code and file?

Comment: Done. please have a glance

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I resolved it now. The error is gone.

Comment: I changed this line along with your code change suggestion const tokenforPic = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: ["User.Read"],
      account: accounts[0],
    });

from const tokenforPic = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: ["User.Read"],
      account: accounts[0],
    });.then((data) => data.accessToken)

Comment: @Lakshmi Ah, good, because I was at a bit of a loss why passing the request object through again was now making the call consistently fail. Glad it's working for you now. Cheers and good luck!